# Loopback - delete a record with composite keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I just started using loopback and I have this 'Orders' model:

```
{
  "name": "Orders",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "Client": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": 1,
      "required": true
    },
    "OrderId": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": 2,
      "required": true
    },
    "OrderName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Say I want to delete an order using its composite keys (Client and OrderId). I am using this method but it doesn't delete the record:

```
var filter = {
               where: {
                  Client: 'AB123',
                  OrderId: 'ORD1',
                  OrderName: 'Coffee'
               }
            };

Orders.findOne({filter: filter}, function(err, order){
                if(err){
                   console.log(err);
                }else{
                   console.log(order); //prints { Client: 'AB123', OrderId: 'ORD1', OrderName: 'Coffee' }
                   order.destroy();
                }
               });
```

I also tried using deleteById() method but it only accepts one id/key. Any workaround here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Delete methods are not `prototype` i.e. instance based in loopback - you can not do `order.delete()`. You should use [destroyAll](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-destroyall) as it is method that used to delete bulk of records that match certain `where` clause

I am pretty sure if you try to:

```
      var filter = {
           where: {
              Client: 'AB123',
              OrderId: 'ORD1',
              OrderName: 'Coffee'
           }
        };

      Orders.destroyAll(filter.where, function(err, result){
            if(err){
               console.log(err);
            }else{
               console.log('Sucess', result); // {count:X} <- how much records deleted
            }
           });
```